# Should I continue experimenting or not?

Tags: laptop, monitor, ribbon-cable

Good day to you all.

I just accidentally stripped off the thin lining of metal that is found on the eDP cable of a Lenovo laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad 320-14IAP). The thing happened when I removed it from its socket, then I noticed that I had its conductors still held by the socket.

It has 31 conductor strips in total, with 1 totally removed, and with 2 had its orange covering removed.

[image: This is the eDP Cable that I accidentally damaged]

Now the miracle goes, I still had my laptop monitor up and running! Without any issues, of course, since I tested and played games on it.

[image]

For my question, should I still continue opening my laptop, or leave it forever like that? I'm getting worried about removing it then my laptop monitor would fail.

EDIT: I am opening my laptop because I'm adding oil to its hinges (its getting stiff), but its a separate problem. Removing and adding oil to hinges requires the removal of the eDP cable.

EDIT2: The eDP Cable model is DG421. Additionally, this is the female socket of the eDP cable.

[image]

Comment: Ummmm...  Pics or it didn't happen!  Show pictures of the things you're asking about.  Make sure they're sharp.  You can use the button in the post editor to add images directly from your hard drive to your post.

Why do you want to open the laptop in the first place?  Are you doing so with reference to a repair guide or just guessing?  If you experiment with electronics, you *will* damage some of them.  How often this happens will depend on your education and how much effort you put in.  Whether you're able to repair the damage will depend on the same, plus your ingenuity and your tools.

Comment: I am opening my laptop because I'm adding oil to its hinges (its getting stiff), but its a separate problem. Removing and adding oil to hinges requires the removal of the eDP cable.

I edited the post and added pics.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to unplug and connections if all you want to do is lubricate the hinges. Perhaps you did it by accident when you removed something, who knows. @KH had a good point. We don't know about your expertise. Opening up your laptop could endanger your warranty. We cannot be the judge of whether or not you should do this. The only advice I have is to make sure you have no shadow of doubt about what you're doing. Consumer electronics is sophisticated and rightfully so. Producers don't want their consumers to tinker around their products unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: Given that eDP has several differential pairs, you might've gotten very lucky that the channel(s) with one half of the diff-pair open-circuit might still work, just.

Comment: Yeah really hard to say without specific documents, but it's a 31 pin cable and HDMI only needs 19, so with luck it could be redundant.

Comment: Thank you for all of your advice! I am a first year computer engineering student and I'm grateful to have you around. I've decided not to meddle with these things anymore and I won't open my laptop again, unless it's necessary. I think I've gotten lucky for that and I won't test that luck again by removing that eDP cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like two traces had their gold plating removed and one trace delaminated and is probably welded to the matching contact on the female receptacle.  This trace may still make contact, but not at the intended quality.

It might be working because it still makes contact for the moment or it could be a standard multipin connector and that pin isn't used for the video standard your monitor is using(It's a 31 pin cable and you only need 19 pins for HDMI), or it's redundant, or only partially redundant (like an extra power pin that only becomes significant at a certain load).  If this cable is the sole connection for the monitor panel of your laptop, it would include pins for the other functions of the monitor (are the LEDS if any and webcam working?) and you may simply have not detected what's wrong yet.

Just speculation, but I would monitor it in the future and if it becomes unreliable, or intermittently stops working when you jiggle it or when it warms up or operates at high brightness, you should remember this problem.

It wouldn't be a bad idea to look for a repair guide for your laptop.  If you can find the pinout of that connector or the name of the cable, it would be much easier to be certain what the missing pin is intended to do.

Some laptops, particularly Apple's are designed specifically to prevent or discourage user disassembly and repair, but most are not.  The general rule when disassembling an unknown laptop is to find the screws you might miss (because they are hidden behind a battery door, a sticker, a rubber footpad, a piece of plastic flashing, whatever) and make sure you are prying things apart in the correct directions with a suitable tool so as not to damage small plastic parts that you would be unable to repair.  It is your skill and preparation that will determine whether on average you damage things enough to not make it worthwhile and practice makes perfect if this is a skill you want to have.  I would take it apart just to clean it if I wanted to.

Personally, I'd try to find enough information that I could repair it myself, but be warned you may have to spend quite a bit of time searching to find the information you need.  There is also a chance that someone on here will know what that pin is for or how to look it up, so best of luck.

You also need to check for damage on the other side of that connector and you might want to check if the cable is hardwired to something on the other end.  If it's not it may be an easy replacement once you find a suitable part.

By the way, it looks like Lenovo is [friendly to at least some consumer repair](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/320-14iap/parts/HF002201), so you could start by going on their website to look for documentation.

Comment: If you can do so without damaging anything, find out where that cable goes and if it is easily disconnectable on the other end.  If it is, order a replacement cable and when it arrived I would attempt to remove any unwanted parts from the female side.  Fair warning, the piece of metal that ripped off of the cable could be quite well attached to the female connector and you could damage the connector in the process.  You could also contact Lenovo to ask them what that pin is for.  If you can confirm some how that you don't need it, you can just leave it be.